# Getting videos from a playlist

Tags: php, youtube-api

Is there a way to get a listing of videos from a specific playlist? I tried the following call, but it doesn't seem to be giving me a list of videos in that playlist

```
feed://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/USERNAME/playlists/PLAYLIST_ID
```

I want get all the playlists video url and name ...

Thanks in advance,

Comment: don't use the API v2, you should use API v3 https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: @AlexBenfica js or php ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is available in the [JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Retrieving_playlist_information):

> **player.getPlaylist():Array**
>
> This function returns an array of the video IDs in the playlist as
>   they are currently ordered. By default, this function will return
>   video IDs in the order designated by the playlist owner. However, if
>   you have called the setShuffle function to shuffle the playlist order,
>   then the getPlaylist() function's return value will reflect the
>   shuffled order.

Answer (score 1):

That's v2 of the API that was [deprecated over a year ago](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol). You need to use v3.

Start here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list